# Please sort the Tag Synonyms listing by Target tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, sorting, tag-synonyms

I understand sorting the page by created date for development, but it's not really useful now that the list (at least on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms)) is getting long.

I suggest sorting the list by Target tag, to make the information shown much more useful. This will make finding synonyms by browsing easier, and also group together all the synonyms for a given target tag (which is the most important thing).

Presumably, this would be an easy thing to change on the back end.

Comment: Taking no more than 6 to 8 weeks to implement. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meh, changing the sort listing was trivial.

The [nicer change](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) is that now we display a count on the source if it's more than one, **AND** we show the fact that it's a pending synonym if less than 3 people voted for it. That is the less meh change :)

Comment: The count on the source is an awesome idea.  That makes it much easier for us to see which ones need retags.